# Can I use a CASE statement to switch operators in a TSQL WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a complex stored proc, part of which generates dynamic SQL to pivot data in various ways based on a number of factors. For the purposes of this question, I'll illustrate a simplified example.

One of the parameters passed in is a country, and the data for the pivot is then filtered to that country. However, now requirements have changed, and either a country or a continent may be passed in. What I'd like to do, then, is to have a WHERE clause which uses a CASE statement to either use the = operator or an IN clause, depending on the parameter passed.

Simplified database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
(Country VARCHAR(100),
Continent VARCHAR(20)
)
GO
INSERT INTO  Countries
VALUES ('UK','Europe'),('France','Europe'),('Portugal','Europe'),
('USA','North America'),('Canada','North America'),
('Brazil','South America'),('Peru','South America')
GO

CREATE TABLE Orders
(OrderID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
OrderDate DATE,
ShipCity VARCHAR(100),
ShipCountry VARCHAR(100)
)
GO
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderDate, ShipCity, ShipCountry)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), 'London', 'UK'),
    (GETDATE(),'Paris','France'),
    (GETDATE(),'Porto','Portugal'),
    (GETDATE(),'Vale','USA'),
    (GETDATE(),'Cusco','Peru'),
    (GETDATE(),'Montreal','Canada'),
    (GETDATE(),'Rio de Janeiro','Brazil')
GO
```

Here's my latest attempt at the stored proc (which clearly doesn't work):

```
CREATE PROC TestProc @Country VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Country='Europe' THEN o.ShipCountry IN (SELECT Country FROM Countries c WHERE c.Continent='Europe')
            WHEN @Country='North America' THEN o.ShipCountry IN (SELECT Country FROM Countries c WHERE c.Continent='North America')
            WHEN @Country='South America' THEN o.ShipCountry IN (SELECT Country FROM Countries c WHERE c.Continent='South America')
            ELSE o.ShipCountry=@Country
        END
END
```

I've also tried using a simple case rather than a searched case, but couldn't get that to work either.

TBH, I'm thinking that the best option is to have two option parameters - @Country and @Continent, and to re-write the calling procedures to match. However, having spent quite a while working on this now, I'd like to know if it is, in fact, possible, and if so, how.

Thanks.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression in T-SQL, not a statement, and it returns a scalar value, *not* a boolean result. You need to use explicit `AND` and `OR` logic.

Comment: Though, why not use a parametrised `IN` (and don't pass values with `<>` wrapped around them) and an `OR`? There aren't any countries that have the same name as the continent they are on (assuming you use Australisia or Oceania).

Comment: @Dai - Yes, I know that - I just created this as a simplified example to post here.

Comment: @Larnu - Sorry - having trouble understanding how I'd do that. I get not passing the <> symbols, but the issue is testing for a simple match, or a range of values using IN. Could you elaborate on what the SQL statement would look like?

Comment: just saying, perhaps `@Country` should be `@Continent`.

Comment: Is the transformation always as simple as removing the angle brackets?

Comment: you probably don't want to run that case statement for every row.

Comment: Okay - I think the use of angle brackets has confused the issue - they were just a hangover from the user interface (forcing the continents to appear at the top of a list of options) so I've removed them from my query.  The question remains - how do I (can I?), based on the contents of a parameter, switch my query from a WHERE clause structured as `[Col]=Value` to `[Col] IN ('val1','val2','val3')`?  Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: As a generic approach `[Col]=` can always be expressed as `[Col] IN` so you can write  `[Col] IN (...)`  with the sub query inside the `IN` made dependent on the parameter value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(100) = 'France';

SELECT * 
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE 
        o.ShipCountry IN (SELECT Country 
                          FROM Countries c 
                          WHERE c.Continent=CASE @Country WHEN '<Europe>' 
                                                         THEN 'Europe'
                                                         WHEN '<North America>'
                                                         THEN 'North America'
                                                         WHEN '<South America>'
                                                         THEN 'South America'
                                                         ELSE ''
                                                         END
                                or c.Country = @Country)
```

DBFIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f15c9e79ff98789ec985556f76017985

EDIT: It's even possible to do it without `CASE`

```sql
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(100) = '<Europe>';

SELECT o.* 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.Country = o.ShipCountry
WHERE o.ShipCountry = @Country
   OR c.Continent = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Country,'<',''),'>','')
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=801902138e872114e169afba5d3e4422))

Comment: Missing the logic that `o.ShipCountry` should be `= @Country` in the event that @Country is not one of the three specified strings

Comment: Perfect - thank you. I knew it couldn't be as hard as my brain was attempting to make it :-)

Comment: Doing it without even needing a case is just showing off 

Answer (score 2):

you cor make following query.

If the first query doesn't have a result, the second will be tested.

If one is true the row will be selected

```
DECLARE @country varchar;
SELECT * 
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.ShipCountry IN (SELECT Country FROM Countries c WHERE c.Continent=

    CASE 
        WHEN @Country='<Europe>' THEN 'Europe'
        WHEN @Country='<North America>' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN @Country='<South America>' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE ''
    END) OR o.ShipCountry = @Country
```

Comment: I came up with a near identical answer. Illustrated in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5a84488c6135ea3ce2fcbb7f82a0727).

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you use Australasia or Oceania for the continent (and not Australia), seems you should just use a parametrised `IN` here (and not wrap continent names in less/greater than (`<>`) symbols):

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.TestProc @Country VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT {List of Explicit Columns you need goes here}
    FROM dbo.Orders O
         JOIN dbo.Countries C ON O.ShipCountry = C.Country
         --If, for some reason, you don't have details of all relevant countries, use a LEFT JOIN
    WHERE @Country IN (O.ShipCountry, C.Continent);
END
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9dbda6f2f66839ac36bbaac3820fbedc)

Comment: Okay - that's cool. Really interesting to see another way to tackle this. Thanks for your help.